# how to get the push id value in firebase web

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Firebase DB screenshot]

I want to get the value(111122223333) of the push id in AllocEmp.
firebase DB:

```
{
  "AllocEmp" : {
    "-L3c47chqb35p0Ndo_XB" : "111122223333"
  },
  "complaintDate" : "Wed Jan 10 18:40:34 GMT+05:30 2018",
  "complaintDesc" : "ggshwhwuuww\ngshhsjsn",
  "complaintLM" : "annA",
  "complaintLoc" : "ist",
  "complaintName" : "Continous Fluctuations",
  "defaultTime" : "Thu Jan 11 00:40:34 GMT+05:30 2018",
  "department" : "Electricity",
  "resolvingTime" : "6",
  "uid" : "123456788765"
}
```

im using the code:

```
    var fb = 
    firebase.database().ref().child('UserComplaints').child('AllocEmp');
    fb.once('value', snap => {
        alert(snap.val);
    });
```

this code returns null.
please help me

Answer (score 1):

you're not calling `val()` method , you're missing the parentheses

what you should do is

```
var fb = firebase.database().ref().child('UserComplaints/AllocEmp/1515589858255');
fb.once('value', snap => {
    alert(snap.val()); //here is the problem
});
```

Comment: Still have problem.Now its alerting "[object Object]"

Comment: var fb = firebase.database().ref().child('UserComplaints/AllocEmp/1515589858255');
fb.once('value', snap => {
    alert(snap.key); //here the child name is returning correctly(AllocEmp)
});

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue. What happens here is that call backs are run later so console only tells that it is an object. So u can either use wait () and set Timeout . But obviously it is a wrong practice. Enable a function call in the code to make it synch .
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using `snap.val`. Since val is a function not an expression. Use `snap.val()`. Also remeber it returns an object so try to console it not alert or you can stringify the object to alert.Like this :-

```
let values = []
var fb = 
firebase.database().ref().child('UserComplaints').child('AllocEmp');
fb.once('value', snap => {
    console.log(snap.val()); // to console object
    Object.keys(snap.val()).map(k => {
        console.log(snap.val()[k])
        values.push(snap.val()[k])
    })
    alert(JSON.stringify(snap.val())) // to alert object
});
console.log(values)
```

Comment: var fb = firebase.database().ref().child('UserComplaints');
         fb.on('value', function(snap){
  snap.forEach(function(data){
  alert(JSON.stringify(data.child('AllocEmp').val())); });
  });                                                                                                                                           This code returns {key:value}.how can i split only the value from it @Himanshu

Comment: I have edited my code and use `Object.keys()` to get the keys of object and map through the object to get values inside it